# Sencha touch 2 - list not showing up

Tags: javascript, listview, sencha-touch-2

I am getting pretty desperate about this code and have no idea why it is not working. I am trying to load list from json file. He is my code:

views:
main view

```
    Ext.define('Alerts.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',

    config: {

        items: [
        {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            docked: 'top',
            title: 'Topp Toolbar',

            items: [{
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Alerts',
                id: 'alertsButton',
                handler : function(){
                    //alert('tap')
                    var pnl = Ext.getCmp('hiddenPanel');
                    pnl.showBy(this,"tl-bl");
                }
            }]

        },
        {
            xtype: 'AlertsList'

        },
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            id: 'hiddenPanel',
            // We give it a left and top property to make it floating by default
            left: 0,
            top: 40,

            // Make it modal so you can click the mask to hide the overlay
            modal: true,
            hideOnMaskTap: true,

            // Make it hidden by default
            hidden: true,
            // Set the width and height of the panel
            width:  400,
            height: 400,

            // Here we specify the #id of the element we created in `index.html`
            contentEl: 'content',

            // Style the content and make it scrollable
            styleHtmlContent: true,
            scrollable: true,

            // Insert a title docked at the top with a title
            items: [
                {
                    docked: 'top',
                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                    title: 'Add new',
                    items: [{
                        iconCls: 'add',
                        iconAlign : 'right',
                        id: 'newIcon',
                        handler : function(){
                            alert('icon')
                            //var pnl = Ext.getCmp('hiddenPanel');
                            //pnl.showBy(this,"tl-bl");
                        }
                    }]
                }


            ]
        }
        ]
    }
});
```

AlertsList view:

```
    Ext.define('Alerts.view.AlertsList', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    requires: 'Ext.dataview.List',
    xtype: "AlertsList",


    config: {

        fullscreen: true,
        title: 'list',
        layout: 'fit',
        items: [
        {
            xtype: 'list',
            store: 'Alert',
            itemTpl: '<h1>item<h1>{name}',
        }
        ]

    }
});
```

model:

```
Ext.define('Alerts.model.Alert', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {
        fields: ['name', 'reason', 'enabled', 'notify', 'phone']
    }


});
```

store:

```
Ext.define("Alerts.store.Alert", {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    config: {
            model: "Alerts.model.Alert",
            autoLoad: true,

            proxy: {
                type: "ajax",
                url : "app/store/Alerts.json",
                reader: {
                    type: "json",
                    rootProperty: "alerts"
                }
            }
    }

});
```

When i run the code, app loads fine, without any warns/errors - console is clear.

[image: Picture of app]

Comment: I also have this problem, a lot :(

Answer (score 1):

The main reason of the wrong behavior is that the store was not created before. Try to add the following changes. Add `alias: 'store.alerts'` to `Alert` store. Then use it as `store: {type: 'alerts'}` in the `AlertsList`. As mentioned [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?187153-The-specified-Store-cannot-be-found), this creates a store instance for you. Also I found some issues with the app layout, so I attach here short version of your code with my changes:

```
Ext.define('Test.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    config: {
        layout: 'fit',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            docked: 'top',
            title: 'Topp Toolbar'
        }, {
            xtype: 'AlertsList'
        }]
    }
});
Ext.define('Test.view.AlertsList', {
    extend: 'Ext.dataview.List',
    xtype: "AlertsList",
    config: {
        store: {
            type: 'alerts'
        },
        itemTpl: '<h1>item<h1>{name}',
    }
});
Ext.define('Test.model.Alert', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: ['name', 'reason', 'enabled', 'notify', 'phone']
    }
});
Ext.define("Test.store.Alert", {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'store.alerts',
    config: {
        model: "Test.model.Alert",
        autoLoad: true,
        proxy: {
            type: "ajax",
            url: "app/store/Alerts.json",
            reader: {
                type: "json",
                rootProperty: "alerts"
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @kio21 , can you please have a look at my sencha touch problem ? link [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22457136/sencha-touch-with-phonegap-using-sencha-cmd-and-phonegap-build-causes-error)

Comment: Have the same problem, even made the store beforehand and filtered it. It has items, it's so annoying when Sencha simply refuses to show stuff, no idea what the problem is. And you solution just causes the app to freeze (yes I disabled the filtering to test it).